# How to Download Minimum Requirement of WordPress (Not Themes )

Tags: theme-development

This is not about themes! but WP core files.
I am using WordPress just for sake of it's security and Routing engine. I do not need any slat and surges on top WP like commenting, language,.... What I really need is Page, Taxonomy and Custom Post Type. Is there any way to download WordPress is custom mode? without having to download hundreds of un necessary tools (in my case)  Something like Download Builder in jQuey UI to download only what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not exist unless you fork WordPress, and those modifications will very likely compromise its security and give vey minimal gains to performance.

There are projects out there that try to do this, but they're not used by many, or as well maintained as WordPress Core.

WordPress is not built as a core library with addons like jQuery and other projects are. You can disable comments, or turn off localisation, but you do this by not using localisation APIs, or by disabling things at runtime. Those APIs still get loaded though, you're just unhooking things.

You'll also find that some of these unused tools are surprisingly well used internally. For example, navigation menus are terms in a custom taxonomy, and the individual menu items are a custom post type.

Generally, the best way to do what you want is to just not use those features or call those APIs in the plugins and theme. If the loading of those parts of the codebase is causing considerably performance loss, or even has a measurable performance cost, then this implies that you've either got a site that loads faster than the top 0.01% of WordPress sites, or, the plugins and theme are built very poorly or doing something very expensive.

Comment: Thanks Tom, this was very informative and helpful

Comment: As a guide, these tend to be the top performance killers in WP plugins/themes: 1) remote HTTP requests 2) Fetching posts by the contents of their post meta 3) ordering things randomly 4) exclusions, e.g. I want all X but not Y 5) settings posts per page to -1 6) synchronous image processing. Eliminating those will give massive performance gains in 99% of WP sites. Also use a persistent object cache